# Highlight text in WKWebview

Tags: ios, wkwebview

How to highlight text in WKWebView? I have search option in my app which will search text inside WKWebview. I have to highlight the searched text in WKWebView. Can anyone help me how to do it?

I have HTML string to load in WKWebview

My code would look like

```
webView2.loadHTMLString("<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What does your code look like?

Comment: you want to search inside a website or pdf file?

Comment: @ZGski My question is updated. Please check it

Comment: @ZouhairSassi My question is updated. Please check it

Comment: @Manimurugan Sorry ican't help you in that